# Fastest way to read huge numpy arrays (with image data) from hDf5 files

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, h5py

I have huge number of images, which I prepossessed and stored them (stored the numpy array of dimensions (22500,3,224,224) of floats) on the disk using hdf5 file formatting. The hdf5 file came out to be of size 22 GB.

I used the h5py library of python for this. I used the following code to create the files.

```
h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
h5f.create_dataset('data' , data=myNumpyArray)
h5f.close()
```

I have a machine learning program which learns on this data. So I have an iterator which runs on these files(I have huge data, so I made 8 files of 22GB each). The iterator loads each file and trains the network. This loading of files is however very very slow. It is taking around 15 mins to load a file. I am using the below code to load the files.

```
h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'r')
myNumpyArray= h5f['data'][:]
h5f.close()
```

So to run 100 iterations on the data, I am spending 15*8*100 (multiplied it by 8 because I have 8 files)  = 12,000 minutes (only on file-reading) which I cant afford.

I am doing something like this for the first time and am not sure if I am doing the correct thing.

Can someone help me how to reduce the file-reading time?Or is my way of writing the data itself is wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, 
Vijetha.

Comment: how much ram does your instance have? if you're data is bigger than the ram, you'll be spooling to disk which will be very slow

Comment: @maxymoo makes a good point. I would try making 800 files each 220 MB, or looping over something like h5f['data'][chunksize*i:chunksize*(i+1)]

Comment: The `[:]` operator will create a copy of the array in RAM, is that really what you want? Do you modify the data itself? According to http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage data in HDF5 is stored contigously by default, which means access to any element is basically instant and needs no RAM.

Comment: @maxymoo I have 128 GB on my system and my data is way bigger than that.

Comment: @scf I tried looping over the data using the command " myNumpyArray= h5f['data'][0:150] ". But on the whole it is taking the same amount of time as it takes to load the entire file at a time. So I am stuck here.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa I dont have to modify the data at all. All I need to do it access the data and use it. I tried using the chunk_size parameter as written in post, but I couldn't find a good chunk size that could reduce my reading speed.

Comment: Can you try memory-mapping the files? You can mmap the whole file or parts of the file. Since your files are very large, mapping parts of the file as needed could be faster. I don't know if this is possible in python, but just check.

Comment: I believe hdf5 has the disadvantage of having to read the entire file into RAM before you can access any part of it. Huge collections of image tiles, such as used in deep learning are better stored in something like LMDB. You will get screaming fast reads compared to what you are doing now. You might also check out leveldb. Both have easy Python interfaces.

Comment: h5py reading of huge arrays does not have much performance overhead over just streaming binary data from a file. This is kind of as fast as it gets unless you use better hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Use an SSD — you can buy a 500GB external for around $200 these days, or if you're on AWS, it will only set you back around $1.50 a day to rent an EBS SSD.

It takes 55 seconds for me when i read in 100 row chunks, and I'm just on a 8GB Macbook Air; should be much faster on a higher powered machine.

```
m = np.random.random((20000,3,255,255))
h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
h5f.create_dataset('data' , data=m)
h5f.close()
def access_data(d):
     for i in range(200):
         a = d[i*100:(i+1)*100]


h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'r')
%time access_data(h5f['data'])

CPU times: user 84.8 ms, sys: 35.4 s, total: 35.5 s
Wall time: 55.7 s
```

Comment: Yes, I have 64 bit python, I ran the same code and it said "accessed in 284 seconds." Is there a chance that when you ran the above code, the array 'm' is stored in the cache? Also I have  32 processors and a GPU on my computer. Do you think there is any additional overhead that is present because of this system configuration?

Comment: no it's not caching, i just retimed the data access after restarting python, and got 1min 4s this time, strange that it's running so much slower for you. Do you have a solid state drive? that could be speeding things up for me. Anyway you might want to look into another type of datastore like LMDB as suggested by  @svohara above, hdf5 is a bit old-school.

Comment: I just tried loading from SSD and it is 30 times faster now. It took around 8 seconds to load. But I have huge data and can't store everything on SSD. What would be best way to load from Hard Drive? And thank you @maxymoo, I understood why it was taking a lot of time for me now.

Comment: i don't have an easy answer for you unfortunately. maybe you could write a script which copies the hdf5 files to the SSD as you need them, then deletes them when they're done? otherwise maybe look into LMDB, but i've never used it so i can't vouch for it.

Comment: that said, you can buy a 500GB SSD for around $200 these days so this may actually be your best option considering you've already proved that this will be performant ... rather than messing around for weeks trying to get something else to work

Comment: btw i've edited my answer to suggest an ssd, if you want to accept it as correct

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the answer. This issue was really bugging me for around 2 weeks now. Thanks again.